# Regex to split a sentence by recurring key words

Tags: c#, regex, string

I am currently attempting to use Regular Expressions to split a sentence up based on specific key words used inside the sentence. The first word will be key word, then the next section will be a section of words by it self up until the next key phrase is used. the issue I am currently having is that I would like to use some of those key words inside the section of words between the first and second key words. for example:

'PLAY paradise by the dashboard light BY meatloaf'

the key words being Play, and By. the issue is that 'by' is used inside the middle section of the sentence. is there a method in which I could skip those potential key words inside the middle section of text, or would it be impossible?

Comment: How would the regex know that something is the middle of a sentence

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the keywords/instructions are always uppercase and the other information is lower case like in your example:

```
string source = "PLAY paradise by the dashboard light BY meatloaf";
var separators = new string[] { "PLAY", "BY" };

var result = source.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

If that is not the case then I would recommend you to change the keywords you use internally to something that you won't find in a song name.